# How to add a class to a specific section of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have the below line in the user dropdown menu in the header of my app.

```
<%= link_to "profile (#{user.notifications.count})", current_user %>
```

This should show `profile (3)` if the user has three notifications. I want to color the `profile` a different color from the `(3)`.

Is the best way to do this to give the two different parts different classes? If so, how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `do` block:

```
<%= link_to current_user do %>
  profile (<span class='notifications_count'><%= user.notifications.count %></span>)
<% end %>
```

This will put a span with html class '.notifications_count' inside the `<a></a>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. I think I prefer doing it this way, as I find it a little easier to read. (the line doesn't get too long.)

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to accomplish that is to use `span`, like so

```
<%= link_to raw("<span style='color: #000'>profile</span> (#{user.notifications.count})"), current_user %>
```

or if you don't want to insert inline CSS, like so

```
<%= link_to raw("<span class='your_profile_class'>profile</span> (#{user.notifications.count})"), current_user %>
```

Comment: You can either use `html_safe` or `raw` like I did in my answer.